# Can't draw on canvas .What could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw something very basic to my canvas but its not drawing anything neither showing any errors to fix. what could be the issue here ?

Here's my code :

I also tried moving the js code to an external js file but did't work.

```
<body>
<canvas
  id="myCanvas"
  width="800"
  height="500"
  style="border:1px solid #474747;"
></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect = (10, 100, 15, 400);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with:

```
ctx.fillRect = (10, 100, 15, 400);
```

[`.fillRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) is a method which takes a `x, y, width, height` as it parameters, so you need to call it like so:

```
ctx.fillRect(10, 100, 15, 400);
```

See example below:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(10, 100, 15, 400);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px solid #474747;"></canvas>
```

Comment: omg. i didn't notice that at all :) thanks for pointing it out .

Comment: @zenitsu no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.fillRect = (10, 100, 15, 400);` <-- fillRect() is a function, you're using it as an expression.

```js
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(10, 100, 15, 400);
```

```html
<canvas
  id="myCanvas"
  width="800"
  height="500"
  style="border:1px solid #474747;"
></canvas>
```